# mysql delete records with duplicated grouped columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

i have a table with structure like below

[image]

i want to delete all the duplicate records with same fields, the fields are **BUY_ITEM** and **ALSO_BUY**..

for example on pic above RULE_ID number 2 and 7 both has **CD-ROM** and **MOUSE** as `fields` **BUY_ITEM** and **BUY_ALSO**.

So i want to keep only the first record with `RULE_ID` = **2**, and delete the second record with `RULE_ID` = **7**

the result would be like this

[image]

i'm using `SELECT DISTINCT` to filter the duplicated records and here's the query

```
select distinct BUY_ITEM, ALSO_BUY from result
```

and got result like this

[image]

but i don't know the query to delete the duplicated records with **grouped column** (BUY_ITEM and ALSO_BUY) as criteria..

could you tell me how to do that?

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `join` in the `delete` command.  So, you can summarize the data to get what you need:

```
delete t
    from table t join
         (select buy_item, also_buy, min(rule_id) as minid
          from table t
          group by buy_item, also_buy
          having count(*) > 1
         ) ba
         on t.buy_item = ba.buy_item and t.also_buy = ba.also_buy
    where rule_id > minid;
```

Comment: thx for the reply.. the query is still error, i've tried to fix it but it won't do..the error is at `delete t from table t join`.. the error message was **table t is not defined**. and if i were to execute this query, is the `RULE_ID` with value **7** get deleted and `RULE_ID` with value = **2** is kept instead?

Comment: @SoniGunz . . . The query works on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7459).  You can run the query with a `select` first to see what will be deleted.

Comment: it's actually worked! i mistype `t.also_buy` with `t.buy_item`.. no wonder if i got an error.. thank you very much bro.. :)